# Apps Script Trigger from Library Won't Work: Function Can't Be Found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, libraries

I have a trigger programmed in Apps Script for Google Sheets, and in the original project, it's being created to call a private function that fires when a sheet is edited. On the original project, it works, but when I deploy it, and try to use the deployment in another spreadsheet, the triggers fail, claiming that the private function can't be found.

> Script function not found: colorTab_

I've also tried programming the handler function as a closure, so that it exists in the same function where the trigger is made, but that didn't work, either.

Here's an example of the trigger:

```
function colorTabTrigger_() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
  .filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == this.colorTab_.name);
  if (triggers.length != 0) {
    triggers.forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(this.colorTab_.name)
    .forSpreadsheet(SS)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

The obvious solution, make the handler public, is not possible, since it uses a lot of other private methods, and to do that would expose a method the end user doesn't need to see; and I can't just copy it into the other file's apps script because that wouldn't be proper programming and would force me to make a bunch of other stuff public by cascade, since it uses private functions and variables.

How do I make this work?

Comment: `end user doesn't need to see`. Don't you have to share the library with the end user for libraries to even work?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, but not every function you create has to be public. You can make them private if the function is not going to be a macro in use.

Comment: Regardless, won't the end user already have "view" access to the private function?

Comment: @TheMaster They will not...because it's private. Only the library can see it. So it's kind of like how one would program using closures, or using private methods in C# or something: you can see them, but once the library is released, or the method is called (if this were javascript), the private function can't be reached, only public ones. By the way, if you want to continue this, we should move this to chat.

Comment: This question is discussed in the [community chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54867500#54867500)

Answer (score 1):

As [@TheMaster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) explain that:

> To include a library in your project you must have at least view-level access to it. If you aren't the author of the library that you want to include, contact the author and request access.

Found in the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries?hl=en#gain_access_to_a_library).

And the trigger does not work when added to the library since:

> Simple triggers created in library are not triggered by the including script.

Also mentioned in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries?hl=en#:%7E:text=in%20the%20library.-,Triggers,-Simple%20triggers%20created)